# iOS: Will this method work on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, 64-bit, 32-bit

I need a way to detect if iOS device is 64 bit or 32 bit.  My App is 64 bit compatible. So I believe this should work. Please let me know if it won't. I tested it on a 64 bit iPad and it seems to work, but need to make sure.

```
if (sizeof(void*) == 4) {

} else if (sizeof(void*) == 8) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For reference, the canonical way to check this at compile time is with:

```
#if __LP64__
#endif
```

This is a preprocessor define that will be intrinsically defined by the compiler when generating 64-bit code.

I'm struggling to imagine when there would be a compelling reason to determine this at run time instead of compile time, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Indeed a precompile macro will also increase the apps stability and speeds. Since an iOS app is fat binary which contains both a 32 en 63 bit slice.

Comment: I just saw the answer above in another stackoverflow question. This seems to be the best way however. Will it be best if I implement this above the @implementation or the prefix.pch?

Comment: Absent a specific reason to the contrary, conventional wisdom would dictate that you should be determining this at compile time.

Comment: My opinion is that you should make the size of code that is conditionally different between architectures as small as possible, however that works for your app.

Answer (score 0):

It does work, even in the simulators. You can test it on the iPad 2 simulator and  the code will take the 32 bit path, where as the iPhone 6 simulator takes the other code path.